# How to print '%d' & '%s' in a class in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, oop, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a script which counts some specific words and gives me specific count of the words.

I'm currently stuck in printing data, from the class.

My next task would be put these values in a excel file using a data driven framework.

Here's what i have done until now:

```
a = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(a, "html.parser")


class counter_class:
    def count(self, tittle, block_code):
        blockcode_passed = block_code.count("Passed")
        blockcode_blocked = block_code.count("Blocked")
        blockcode_fail = block_code.count("Failed")
        blockcode_retest = block_code.count("Retest")
        blockcode_cannot_test = block_code.count("Connot Test")
        blockcode_completed = block_code.count("Completed")
        blockcode_passwc = block_code.count("Pass With Concern")
        blockcode_untested = block_code.count("Untested")

        print '%s' + ' ' + '%d' %(tittle,blockcode_passed)
        print '%s' + ' ' + '%d' %(tittle,blockcode_fail)
        print "Apps Gateway(Untested)" + ' ' + '%d' %(blockcode_untested)
        print "Apps Gateway(Blocked)" + ' ' + '%d' %(blockcode_blocked)
        print "Apps Gateway(Retest)" + ' ' + '%d' %(blockcode_retest)
        print "Apps Gateway(Cannot Test)" + ' ' + '%d' %(blockcode_cannot_test)
        print "Apps Gateway(Completed)" + ' ' + '%d' %(blockcode_completed)
        print "Apps Gateway(Pass With Concern)" + ' ' + '%d' %(blockcode_passwc)




apps_gateway = soup.find_all("div", {"id":"group-3191427"})
apps_gateway_str = str(apps_gateway)
apps_gateway_obj=counter_class()
apps_gateway_obj.count("appsgateway",apps_gateway_str)
```

The second part of the code works but the 1st part of the code:

```
print '%s' + ' ' + '%d' %(tittle,blockcode_passed)
print '%s' + ' ' + '%d' %(tittle,blockcode_fail)
```

Gives me error:

```
print '%s' + ' ' + '%d' %(tittle,blockcode_passed)
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in the order of operations. What's actually being executed is: `print '%s' + ' ' + ('%d' %(tittle,blockcode_passed))`.

Python is trying to use `tittle` in place of the `%d` argument. You can change it with either:

```
print ('%s' + ' ' + '%d') %(tittle,blockcode_passed)
# or
print "%s %d" %(tittle,blockcode_passed)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're applying the formatting with the `%` operator to just the last string, in this case `'%d'`. This won't work with the `title` argument.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by removing the string concatenation from the format strings: `'%s' + ' ' + '%d'` -> `'%s %d'`. The problem with your syntax is that the string formatting is done first, before the concatenation happens, so in your case:

```
'%s' + ' ' + '%d' % ('s', 2)
```

python tries to replace `%d` with the first element of the tuple you give it, which is a string, giving you the error `TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str`.

Answer (score 0):

## Beware the operator precedence

```
'%s' + ' ' + '%d' %(tittle,blockcode_passed)
```

means

```
'%s' + ' ' + ('%d' %(tittle,blockcode_passed))
```